# No input file error after implementing wildcards

Tags: c++, makefile

## Problem

I have `Makefile`, and I did some tedious work on specifying all of my subroutines : `A.o` through `K.o` (all are in `source` directory) in defining `OBJ` as below. Here is my `Makefile`, and it works as expected.

#### Method that works

```
ProjectName = SomeName
CXX = g++ -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall

OBJ = build/main.o build/A.o \
build/B.o build/C.o \
build/D.o build/E.o \
build/F.o build/G.o \
build/H.o build/I.o \
build/J.o build/K.o \

all: $(ProjectName)

$(ProjectName): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

build/%.o: source/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<
```

---

However, to evade those tedious work, I have implemented the wildcard `$(wildcard source/*.cpp)`, and I think it should work, because what I call is all of those files with `.o` extension that are in `source` directory

#### Methods that does not work

```
ProjectName = SomeName
CXX = g++ -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall

SRC := $(wildcard source/*.cpp)
OBJ := $(patsubst source/%.cpp, build/%.o, $(SRC))

all: $(ProjectName)

$(ProjectName): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

build/%.o: source/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<
```

However, it shows me an error:

`g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What `g++` command line does `make` say right before that? Is it `g++ -o SomeName build/A.o build/B.o `...?

Comment: @DanielH It's g++ -std=c++11 -o SomeName

Comment: Presuming your source files and headers are all in the `./source` directory, then `SOURCES := $(wildcard source/*.cpp)` and then `OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:source/%.cpp=%.o)`  (your use of `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` is also a bit shuffled around, but it will work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a simple typo: you call your array `OBJ` but you reference it as `OBJS`.